# VB NET SQL Stack Column Chart

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have following SQL Result

```
Category1  Category2 Product Amount

A          Ax        Ax1       5

A          Ax        Ax2       4

A          Ay        Ay1       7

B          Bx        Bx1       3

B          Bx        Bx2       9

B          Bx        Bx3       8
```

...
and I need a Stacked Column chart for vb like this one:

[IMAGE: Stack Column Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYFd7.png)

How do I have to configurate the Series, sodass all "A"-Products are stacked in the first column etc.

I tried this:

```
Dim Products As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT Category1, Category2, Product, Amount FROM Company.dbo.Assets",cn)

Chart1.DataSource = Products.ExecuteReader
Chart1.Series.Add("S1")
Chart1.Series("S1").XValueMember = "Product"
Chart1.Series("S1").YValueMembers = "Ammount"
```

How should I continue???

Comment: please format your question proper!

Answer (score 1):

Add more series and set the Series.Charttype property of each of your series.

For more info have a look at:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.series.charttype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx